# How can I output a docx from docxtemplater.js for input in jszip

Tags: javascript, blob, jszip, docxtemplater

Using the examples from [jszip](https://stuk.github.io/jszip/) and [docxtemplater](https://docxtemplater.readthedocs.io/en/latest/generate.html) I am trying to add multiple docx-Documents to a zip archive and I am failing. My archive only contains docx-files with 0 Bytes that are not readable.

I think I don't understand how I can add the docx-files in binary mode to the archive.  I added the rather long example code that I fused from the examples mentioned above.

Can you tell me how I have to modify the output of the generate()-function or the addition of the files to the zip-archive?

```
<html>
<body>
    <button onclick="zip_docx()">Generate document</button>
</body>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/docxtemplater/3.17.9/docxtemplater.js"></script>
<script src="https://unpkg.com/pizzip@3.0.6/dist/pizzip.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/FileSaver.js/1.3.8/FileSaver.js"></script>
<script src="https://unpkg.com/pizzip@3.0.6/dist/pizzip-utils.js"></script>
<script src="jszip.min.js"></script>
<!--
Mandatory in IE 6, 7, 8 and 9.
-->
<!--[if IE]>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="https://unpkg.com/pizzip@3.0.6/dist/pizzip-utils-ie.js"></script>
<![endif]-->
<script>
function loadFile(url,callback){
    PizZipUtils.getBinaryContent(url,callback);
}
function zip_docx(){
  var zip = new JSZip();
  var file1 = generate("file1");
  var file2 = generate("file2");
  var file3 = generate("file3");
  zip.file("file1.docx", file1);
  zip.file("file2.docx", file2);
  zip.file("file3.docx", file3);

  zip.generateAsync({type:"blob"})
  .then(function(content) {
      // see FileSaver.js
      saveAs(content, "example.zip");
  });
  }
function generate() {
    loadFile("https://docxtemplater.com/tag-example.docx",function(error,content){
        if (error) { throw error };

        // The error object contains additional information when logged with JSON.stringify (it contains a properties object containing all suberrors).
        function replaceErrors(key, value) {
            if (value instanceof Error) {
                return Object.getOwnPropertyNames(value).reduce(function(error, key) {
                    error[key] = value[key];
                    return error;
                }, {});
            }
            return value;
        }

        function errorHandler(error) {
            console.log(JSON.stringify({error: error}, replaceErrors));

            if (error.properties && error.properties.errors instanceof Array) {
                const errorMessages = error.properties.errors.map(function (error) {
                    return error.properties.explanation;
                }).join("\n");
                console.log('errorMessages', errorMessages);
                // errorMessages is a humanly readable message looking like this :
                // 'The tag beginning with "foobar" is unopened'
            }
            throw error;
        }

        var zip = new PizZip(content);
        var doc;
        try {
            doc=new window.docxtemplater(zip);
        } catch(error) {
            // Catch compilation errors (errors caused by the compilation of the template : misplaced tags)
            errorHandler(error);
        }

        doc.setData({
            first_name: 'John',
            last_name: 'Doe',
            phone: '0652455478',
            description: 'New Website'
        });
        try {
            // render the document (replace all occurences of {first_name} by John, {last_name} by Doe, ...)
            doc.render();
        }
        catch (error) {
            // Catch rendering errors (errors relating to the rendering of the template : angularParser throws an error)
            errorHandler(error);
        }

        var out=doc.getZip().generate({
            type:"blob",
            mimeType: "application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.wordprocessingml.document",
        }) //Output the document using Data-URI
        //saveAs(out,"output.docx")
        return out
    })
}
</script>
```

Comment: It looks like your `generate` method is not returning anything. On first sight, it might seem like the line `return out` is responsible for the return value. But this is not the case, as this return statement is inside a callback function.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After researching the comment of muellermarkus, I was consulting with the leader of the project and [I opened an issue on github](https://github.com/open-xml-templating/docxtemplater/issues/538). There is an answer there which I copy here as a reference. The main hurdle was the addition of {base64: true} as option when the docx-file is added to the archive.

```
<html lang="en">
<body>
    <button onclick="generate()">Generate document</button>
</body>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/docxtemplater/3.17.9/docxtemplater.js"></script>
<script src="https://unpkg.com/pizzip@3.0.6/dist/pizzip.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/FileSaver.js/1.3.8/FileSaver.js"></script>
<script src="https://unpkg.com/pizzip@3.0.6/dist/pizzip-utils.js"></script>

<script>
var zipDocs = new PizZip();
function loadFile(url,callback){
    PizZipUtils.getBinaryContent(url,callback);
}

function generate() {

    loadFile("https://docxtemplater.com/tag-example.docx",function(error,content){
        if (error) { throw error };

        // The error object contains additional information when logged with JSON.stringify (it contains a properties object containing all suberrors).
        function replaceErrors(key, value) {
            if (value instanceof Error) {
                return Object.getOwnPropertyNames(value).reduce(function(error, key) {
                    error[key] = value[key];
                    return error;
                }, {});
            }
            return value;
        }

        function errorHandler(error) {
            console.log(JSON.stringify({error: error}, replaceErrors));

            if (error.properties && error.properties.errors instanceof Array) {
                const errorMessages = error.properties.errors.map(function (error) {
                    return error.properties.explanation;
                }).join("\n");
                console.log('errorMessages', errorMessages);
                // errorMessages is a humanly readable message looking like this :
                // 'The tag beginning with "foobar" is unopened'
            }
            throw error;
        }
        const array = ['John','Jane']
        array.forEach(function(name){
          var zip = new PizZip(content);
          var doc;
          try {
              doc=new window.docxtemplater(zip);
          } catch(error) {
              // Catch compilation errors (errors caused by the compilation of the template : misplaced tags)
              errorHandler(error);
          }
          console.log(name);
          doc.setData({
              first_name: name,
              last_name: 'Doe',
              phone: '0652455478',
              description: 'New Website'
          });

          try {
            // render the document (replace all occurences of {first_name} by John, {last_name} by Doe, ...)
            doc.render();
          }
          catch (error) {
            // Catch rendering errors (errors relating to the rendering of the template : angularParser throws an error)
            errorHandler(error);
          }

          var out=doc.getZip().generate() //Output the document using Data-URI

          zipDocs.file(name+".docx", out, {base64: true});
          console.log(name, " wurde gezippt.");

      })
      var content = zipDocs.generate({ type: "blob" });
      // see FileSaver.js
      saveAs(content, "example.zip");
    })
}
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

It worked for me (with Angular)

**HTML**

```
<input type="file" placeholder="Upload docx template" #docx>
<hr>
<button (click)="readDocxFile(docx)">Save</button>
```

**Function on Component**

```
readDocxFile(elm: any): void {
    const reader = new FileReader();

    if (elm.files.length === 0) {
      console.log('No files selected');
    }

    reader.readAsBinaryString(elm.files.item(0));

    reader.onerror = (event) => {
      console.log('error reading file', event);
    };

    reader.onload = (event) => {
      const content = event.target.result;
      const zip = new PizZip(content);
      this.filesService.save(zip, this.data);
    };
  }
```

**My service**

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';

import * as JSZip from 'JSZip';
import { saveAs } from 'file-saver';
declare const docxtemplater: any;

@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root',
})
export class SaveFilesService {
  constructor() {}

  save(zipContent: any, data: any[]): void {
    const zip = new JSZip();

    data.forEach((val) => {
      const file = this.generate(zipContent, val);
      zip.file(`Word_${val.docNr}.docx`, file);
    });

    zip.generateAsync({ type: 'blob' }).then((content) => {
      saveAs(content, 'example.zip');
    });
  }

  generate(zip: any, val: any): any {
    const doc = new docxtemplater(zip).setData(val).render();
    const out = doc.getZip().generate({
      type: 'blob',
      mimeType:
        'application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.wordprocessingml.document',
    });

    return out;
  }
}
```

Comment: Thank you for sharing. I cannot verify the answer as I don't use Angular and I am not a JS expert.